# null substitute for method returning integer

Tags: java

If a method has to return an object, and it has an option to return null. But if a function has to return an int, what should it do if such return value for `int` cannot be found / generated etc. ? ie throw an exception ? return a bool ? change return type from int to some data object ?

Comment: I don't get your question. If its return type is `int`, you have to return an `int`. Change its return type to `Integer` if you want a reference type.

Comment: try create a method that return int and test it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the Integer wrapping object

```
public Integer returnNull(){
    return null;
}
```

be careful though because this will compile and then throw a NullPointerException

```
public void myMethod(){
    ....
    int i = returnNull();
    ....
}
```

Thanks autoboxing.

Of the options you have suggest you cannot return a boolean.
Throwing an exception is the clean/java way to do it.

Comment: If the return-type is an "optional" Integer, you should only assign it to an Integer & treat that as optional -- ie, check for nulls.

Comment: Is this an actual answer to his question or just a rant against autoboxing?

Comment: @jedwards I have no beef with autoboxing.

Comment: IMO, autoboxing is o.k. and very useful, but auto-unboxing is less useful and  is the root of far too many bugs.

Comment: +1. If it's an exceptional case, then throw an exception. If it's an expected case, use the reference type, and return null.

Answer (score 0):

return -1. Thats the most usual practice with int returns

Comment: only concern is -1 can also be a valid answer.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper valid point.  In some cases methods return Integer.MAX_VALUE or INTEGER.MIN_VALUE or SOME_APPLICATION_DEFINED_CONSTANT instead of -1.  Those are sometimes less likely to be valid answers, e.g. this is the difference in years between two (reasonable) dates.